# How to change first boolean of object in array react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a JSON from API, the response of API is to declare if the task already done,

example of JSON :

```
[ { Name: 'Pre Operation', Checked: false },
  { Name: 'Operation', Checked: false },
  { Name: 'Post Operation', Checked: false } ]
```

How can I update a JSON to be like :

```
[ { Name: 'Pre Operation', Checked: true},
  { Name: 'Operation', Checked: false },
  { Name: 'Post Operation', Checked: false } ]
```

I have tried using this code:

```
var output = jsonResult.map((item)=>{
  if(item.Checked == true){
    item.Checked === false
  }
  return item
})
```

But the JSON doesnt change, and I'm afraid `item.Checked === false` will effected all of `item.Checked` that has `true` value

and if I have a response from API like this:

```
[ { Name: 'Pre Operation', Checked: true},
  { Name: 'Operation', Checked: false },
  { Name: 'Post Operation', Checked: false } ]
```

I need to update a JSON to be like this:

```
    [ { Name: 'Pre Operation', Checked: true},
  { Name: 'Operation', Checked: true},
  { Name: 'Post Operation', Checked: false } ]
```

Anyone can help me how to archieve my goal?

Comment: Is this array of objects (it's not JSON) part of your `this.state`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yep, actually I've `parse` JSON from API, and I got those Array when `console.log`

Comment: But is it part of your `this.state`?

Comment: Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
var arr = [ { Name: 'Pre Operation', Checked: false }, { Name: 'Operation', Checked: false }, { Name: 'Post Operation', Checked: false } ];
  
  function updateStatus(){
    var result = arr.find(({Checked}) => !Checked); 
    if(result) result.Checked = true;
  }
  
 updateStatus(); console.log(arr); // first is updated
 updateStatus(); console.log(arr); // second is updated
 updateStatus(); console.log(arr); // third is updated
 updateStatus(); console.log(arr); // no update
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm misunderstanding the question, but surely you can just..

```
jsonResult[0].Checked = true;
```

edit.. if you want to be less ruthless..

```
jsonResult.some((item) => { if (item.Name = 'Pre Operation') { item.Checked = true; return true; })
```

array.prototype.some is a good way to exist a loop when you've done what you need - once 'true' is returned it will stop looping.